# Swap HDD to change OS?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd, swap

I'm going to a LAN tomorrow, however, they all use windows and we're planning on playing some games that are only for windows. I have a laptop with a pretty SSD of 60GB with Ubuntu that works perfect so far. However, with a partition of windows+game, the space might become a problem. So I was thinking about doing this, but wanted to know if it was going to work before spending 2+ hours by asking here.

I have my original 256GB HDD. If I install windows there from the actual laptop, can I swap then to Ubuntu seamlessly by just swapping the HDD for the SSD? The only information I could find in google was changing the HDD from one computer to another, which would not work for the devices installed, but since this would use 2 different disks for the same computer (physically changing them), I thought it might work.

Will Ubuntu and Windows run after installing Windows in that way? My main concern has to do with the BIOS getting modified by a not so play along Windows and not letting me boot Ubuntu then, but I'm not sure how that works and I am not aware of other potential problems. Are you?

Notes:

- Tried both Wine and VirtualBox; none worked.
- I don't want to delete Ubuntu. It works like a charm for my daily use.
- It's fine physically swapping SSD for HHD and back in the laptop. It will likely be done once or twice in its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the HDD should work fine. The BIOS is not modified by a Windows installation. I did this for myself some time ago on an IBM Thinkpad.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that Windows and Ubuntu are both on their own respective drive, running on the same computer, you shouldn't have any problems.

Now what you can do if your system hardware, and BIOS allows you, you can have both drive physically attached, and all you have to do is change boot-up priority, when you power on the machine.

Again make sure that your system can handle that.  Most new system are able to do that.

Comment: The laptop has only one bay for the HDD, but thanks for your feedback